# ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver

Tags: lxc, keyserver

I tried to launch `lxc` container. But when I give

```
sudo lxc-create -t download ubuntu -n web1
```

it shows this error

> ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing what version of Ubuntu you're using and without knowing what version of lxc-create you have, I'm just going to assume it's 20.04 and 4.0.6, respectively.

You can [see here](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/lxc-4.0.6/templates/lxc-download.in#L59) that by default it's going to look at the `$DOWNLOAD_KEYSERVER` environment variable and, if that's not set, by default it will use `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`.

If you run `dig pool.sks-keyservers.net` you can see it's returning an `NXDOMAIN` status:

```
$ dig pool.sks-keyservers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> pool.sks-keyservers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 39707
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pool.sks-keyservers.net.   IN  A

;; Query time: 47 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 31 20:22:44 PST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

If you go to https://sks-keyservers.net you will see a message indicating that due to repeated GDPR requests they have stopped serving the pool's DNS records. Later versions of LXC are hardcoding `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com` for this value instead.

To use that, you can do:

```
$ DOWNLOAD_KEYSERVER="hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com" lxc-create -t download -n my-container
```

Or just export the variable before running the command, e.g. `export DOWNLOAD_KEYSERVER="hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com"`.

Comment: `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com` also returns an error for me: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`

Comment: I would try adding port 80 to that like `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`. Otherwise, try running the GPG command with `--debug-all` and `-vvv` and look at the logs. I can't reproduce the issue from my machine.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it! Thanks :D
`hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443` also works.

Comment: If to run using `sudo` - there may be issues with environment variables with this way and then `sudo lxc-create -n foocontainer -t download -- --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com` may be better case.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I tried with all methods above, none of them worked and I kept getting

```
Setting up the GPG keyring
ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver
lxc-create: priv-cont: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1616 Failed to create container from template
lxc-create: priv-cont: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 319 Failed to create container priv-cont
```

So, [here](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1094/unable-to-create-lxc-container-error-unable-to-fetch-gpg-key-from-keyserver) I found the flag --no-validate option, which, be aware, **is unsafe**, but works for my learning process. The execution is as follows:
`DOWNLOAD_KEYSERVER="keyserver.ubuntu.com" sudo lxc-create --template download --name priv-cont -- --no-validate`

Comment: Not really solves the underlying issue, but is indeed helpful to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Like @starbeamrainbowlabs said, use the flag `--keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com`. Note the "s" at the end of the protocol string. It is not working anymore without it...

Full working example:

`lxc-create -n mycontainer -t download -- -d debian -r bullseye -a amd64 --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com`